# Custom Core Session Not working in Magento Checkout page

Tags: magento

I have set the custom Magento core session variable in Shopping cart page.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyPoints('4');
```

I need to retrieve the above Session value in checkout page.But It show the empty value while retrieve the session variable in checkout page using below code.

```
echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyPoints();
```

Can any one help this.

Any help much appriciation.

Comment: there is probably something going on with your sessions. check that you have single "frontend" cookie set for both your shopping cart and checkout page. also make sure that "PHPSESSID" (default php session cookie) is NOT set, since Magento overrides it with "frontend" and "adminhtml" cookies

Comment: I would check `System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management  > Cookie Lifetime` to make sure that this value is not set to something very low. Also - just a best practice thing, I would store your variable in `checkout/session` instead of `core/session`.